# how to Colorize Shell Command Line

Tags: shell, colorize

Linux BASH Shell:

1. not Change The Color of  Shell Prompt
2. not Change The Color of  Shell Output line

I just want to only Colorize The Shell Command Line

（looks like under pic yellow）

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3UtA.png)

Comment: Have you tried Bash IT ? It has a lot of [themes](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it/wiki/Themes), see:<br>
https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it You can also create your own theme

Comment: Have a look at https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command, you can hack something based on that.